# xamarin.ios ios-chart BarChartDataSet

Tags: charts, xamarin, xamarin.ios, ios-charts

Just port ios-charts v2.2.3.0 from Xamarin Nuget package manager.

```
public void BarChart(BarChartModel _barChartModel, BarChartView _barChartView, string _fromView, bool animateChart)
    {
        try {
            barChartModel = _barChartModel;
            barChartView = _barChartView;

            barChartView.SetDrawBarShadowEnabled (false);
            barChartView.SetMaxVisibleValueCount (15);
            barChartView.SetPinchZoomEnabled (true);
            barChartView.SetDrawGridBackgroundEnabled (false);
            barChartView.ScaleYEnabled = false;

            // Chart axis' layout configurations
            ChartXAxis xAxis = barChartView.XAxis;
            xAxis.SetLabelPosition (XAxisLabelPosition.Bottom);
            xAxis.SetDrawGridLinesEnabled (false);
            xAxis.SetLabelTextColor (chartTextColor);
            xAxis.SpaceBetweenLabels = 2;
            xAxis.SetAvoidFirstLastClippingEnabled (true);
            xAxis.SetLabelWidth (30f);

            ChartYAxis leftAxis = barChartView.LeftAxis;
            leftAxis.SetLabelCount (10, false);
            leftAxis.SetLabelPosition (YAxisLabelPosition.OutsideChart);
            leftAxis.SpaceTop = 10f;
            leftAxis.SetLabelTextColor (chartTextColor);
            leftAxis.ValueFormatter = new NSNumberFormatter ();

            ChartYAxis rightAxis = barChartView.RightAxis;
            rightAxis.SetDrawGridLinesEnabled (false);
            rightAxis.SetDrawLabelsEnabled (false);

            ChartLegend legend = barChartView.Legend;
            legend.SetPosition (ChartLegendPosition.BelowChartCenter);
            legend.SetForm (ChartLegendForm.Square);
            legend.FormSize = 9f;
            legend.SetFormToTextSpace (11f);
            legend.XEntrySpace = 15f;
            legend.TextColor = chartTextColor;

            // X Axis
            // -- directly get from dataModel.xAxis;
            NSObject[] truncatedXAxis = new NSObject[barChartModel.xAxis.Count];
            for (int t = 0; t < barChartModel.xAxis.Count; t++) {
                if (barChartModel.xAxis [t].Length > 13)
                    truncatedXAxis [t] = NSObject.FromObject (barChartModel.xAxis [t].Substring (0, 11) + "..");
                else
                    truncatedXAxis [t] = NSObject.FromObject (barChartModel.xAxis [t]);
            }

            // Y Axis
            BarChartDataSet[] yDataSets = new BarChartDataSet[barChartModel.yAxis.Count];

            for (int i = 0; i < barChartModel.yAxis.Count; i++) {
                ChartDataEntry[] barEntry = new ChartDataEntry[barChartModel.yAxis [i].Count];
                //List<ChartDataEntry> dataEntryList = new List<ChartDataEntry>();
                for (int j = 0; j < barChartModel.yAxis [i].Count; j++) {
                    barEntry[j] = new ChartDataEntry((float)barChartModel.yAxis [i] [j], j);
                    //dataEntryList.Add(new ChartDataEntry((float)barChartModel.yAxis [i] [j], j));
                }

                //BarChartDataSet yDataSet = new BarChartDataSet (dataEntryList.ToArray(), barChartModel.dataSetLegend [i].ToString());
                // Crashes HERE V
                BarChartDataSet yDataSet = new BarChartDataSet (barEntry, barChartModel.dataSetLegend [i].ToString());
                yDataSet.SetColor(chartColors [i]);

                yDataSets[i] = yDataSet;
            }

            // Combine xAxis & yAxis
            BarChartData data = new BarChartData (truncatedXAxis, yDataSets);
            data.SetValueTextColor (chartTextColor);
            data.SetHighlightEnabled (false);           // Disable highlight selection

            barChartView.SetData(data);
            barChartView.SetNoDataTextDescription ("");
            barChartView.SetDescriptionText (""); // Disable description - barChartData.SetDescription (String.IsNullOrEmpty (dataModel.name) ? "" : dataModel.name);   
            barChartView.SetNoDataText (""); // Text displayed when no data is given ("You need to provide data for the chart.");
            if (animateChart)
                barChartView.AnimateWithYAxisDuration (800);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LogHelper.Debug ("iOSChartHelper", ex.Message, ex);
        }
    }
```

The line below this comment `// Crashes HERE V` is where having crash with below error message throw from binding framework.

> fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type

Have tried changes the `BarchartDataSet` to different variable but no luck.
Does anyone have sample code or solution about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your barEntry array is a ChartDataEntry array. You should use an Array of BarChartDataEntry

```
BarChartDataEntry[] barEntry = new BarChartDataEntry[someIntValue];
```